# Laravel Nova Metric card display custom label

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I'm trying to implement a card with a [trend-metric](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/metrics/defining-metrics.html#trend-metrics) in Laravel Nova. Is there any way to update the label of the card?

So in my case change "Participations Per Station" into something else.

[image: l]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either change the file name, or add this to your `ParticipationsPerStation.php` in `Nova/Metrics`

```
public function name()
{
    return 'Different Name';
}
```

Comment: @PeterPiper happy to help man, if you go to your metric file, you'll see that it extends `Partition` and `Partitions` extends `Metric`, and in `Metric.php` you will find `public function name`, there you can see that it will look for a `name` function in your file first, if it doesn't find it, it will `humanize` the file name.

Comment: awesome thanks! i was so focused on searching for a label method that i must have missed it :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also just set the name in your metric using the name property like this.

```
public $name = 'Total Departments';
```